# How to soundproof floor from neighbors below?

Tags: floor, sound-proofing

We live in an old building in an apartment owned by our family so we can renovate. We go to sleep early so while our house is quiet we can hear our neighbors walking, dragging furniture etc.

I know that tiles are directly glued to the concrete floor. The building is 80 years old with a concrete floor (not sure how thick the floor is) with tiles glued to it with cement perhaps.

We have a budget of 10k, the flat is 67 square meter. We wonder if just doing our bedroom will be sufficient.

I would really like to know what would be the best solution I can apply from my end (*no point in talking with them*), to minimize the impact sounds.

Comment: You have a "budget of 10k". What currency?

Comment: There may be  a "point in talking with them".  Perhaps they also can here your movements and daily activities. Also,  the solution may? involve access to the underside of your concrete floor. (*i don't know, just saying*.)

Comment: try a large thick rug, and see how much that alone helps. It might be enough, and if not, you can use it still after spending more money on treatments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two kinds of “sound control” problems: 1) airborne sounds, and 2) impact sounds.

1. Airborne sounds (talking, tv, etc.). When I first read your statement, I thought this was your problem because it occurs BELOW your unit. As soon as that noise travels in the air up to your apartment, it becomes “airborne sound”.

However, now I think it is an “impact sound” because you’re not complaining about other airborne sounds. Therefore, the clicking noise (from walking on the tile) must remain in the structure until the sound reaches your space.

2. Impact sound (closing doors, heels clicking on floor from walking, etc.).  Impact sound travels through building materials (floor joists, wallboard, etc.) much faster and much more efficiently.

In order to control impact sound, you need to isolate the surrounding material. Some of these problems are “built in” and cannot be resolved easily (or cheaply), which appears to be your situation.

For impact sounds we try to 1) stop floor joists and underlayment from extending under a party wall, 2) provide separate party walls between rooms, and 3) stop roof joists from crossing from room to room, 4) isolate the impact noise. Obviously it’s too late for those techniques.

The easiest remedy is to remove the tile and reinstall it over a sound deadening board to isolate the tile. However, I understand this is not an option. Therefore, I’d 1) check to see if the sound is just as loud in other parts of your apartment. If so it not, then maybe you could rearrange your environment (perhaps sleep in the living room). 2) If it’s just as loud in all parts of the apartment, then I’d build a sound isolation room within your existing bedroom. This may include adding music to mask the sound.

Comment: I sleep with a white noise generator turned on, it helps immensely.

Comment: removing the tiles and installing necessary stuff is an option, why  sound deadening board?

Comment: @user2627775 You question states that your floor is tile on concrete.  Removing tiles exposes concrete floor. What is "necessary stuff" and how is it installed on/under concrete floor?

Answer (score 0):

A first step seems to be put down conventional foam rubber rug padding and rug. You could take it with you if you move , and it adds some decorating options. It won't stop noise coming up the walls but will tend to absorb sound from any source. If budget permits ,drapes also absorb some sound.